# Segmented Control Subview from extension

Tags: ios, swift, uisegmentedcontrol

I'm trying to add a subview below my UISegmentedControl from an extension so when I add more properties to this subview it can be reused from other UISegmentedControls within the app.

It appears in the right place, but for some reason sometimes appears above some segments and sometimes below. Am I missing something?

[image]

So far in my extension, that's what I have:

```
import UIKit

extension UISegmentedControl {
    func addBackgroundView() {
        let backgroundView = UIView();
        backgroundView.frame = self.bounds;
        backgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor.purple;
        self.insertSubview(backgroundView, belowSubview: self);
    }
}
```

And then, I call the extensions function from the viewDidLoad method in the ViewController:

```
self.segmentedControlUnit.addBackgroundView();
```

Comment: try this link : http://www.richardhsu.me/posts/2015/01/26/segmented-control.html

Comment: Reading through the comments in the answers, would the best solution be to (1) subclass UIView instead of UISegmentedControl, (2) Add a UISegementedControl as a subview, (3) expose those things you need of each class - UIView and UISegmentedControl - and (4) add those custom things you wish? More or less, could you get the desired results by *reversing* the order and *subclassing* instead of *extending*?

Answer (score 1):

I dont think you can do this. this is the UI Hierarchy when i select 2nd segment ,
[image]
and this is the UI Hierarchy when i select 3rd segment

so the segment position changes depending on what segment you select.
[image]

Comment: That's the behavior I don't understand. Is it a bug or something? Is it not supposed to be the whole component above and not only some of the segments? I tried to add a view below from the Interface Builder and it works. Shouldn't be the same via code?

Comment: I think this is the default behavior. You have to create your own custom controller for this by wrapping UISegmentedControl. and also you cannot add subView below  UISegmentedControl because all the subViews live inside the UISegmentedControl.

Comment: You can try this `segmentedControl.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "purple_image") , for: .normal, barMetrics: .default)`
add a purple image as background .

Comment: It looks like its sending the segments to the back of the view when changing segment - maybe override `var selectedSegmentIndex: Int` with a `didSet` and try sending the background view to the back again?

Comment: @Keaz this maybe works but as I said I want to do something more complex with the backgroundView. it's not only about adding a backgroundColor, I need a whole view below.

Comment: @Keaz I gave you a +1 cause the screenshots are quite useful to understand the issue but I'm still trying to fix it

Comment: Thanks @VictorRius,
did you try creating a custom UIController by extending UIView and the adding **SegmentedControl** as suvbiew

Answer (score 0):

Try to insert `backgroundView` at index 0 to make sure it below all of subview

```
self.insertSubview(backgroundView, at: 0)
```

Comment: Hi Luan, thanks for the suggestion but still happens the same

Comment: What is your expectation ? Maybe I will have another ways to do that.

Comment: If you can see in the attached images in some segments depending on which are pressed the purple view appears above instead of below and it doesn't allow to read the segment text. That's the issue